# Implementing the UIActivityItemSource protocol

Tags: ios, ios6

I have these protocol methods,

`activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:` and `activityViewController:itemForActivityType:`

but they never get called. How do I tell the `UIActivityViewController` to call them?

I also have an `UIActivityItemProvider` subclass, however I'm confused as to who calls these 2 methods. I'd really appreciate some sample code, as I can't find anything on the web. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the documentation. The array of activity items that you pass to
`-initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:` can be an array of data objects, like strings or images, or it can be array of objects that implement the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol.

If you pass an array of objects that implement the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol then your instance of `UIActivityViewController` will call those methods on your activity items. Those objects do not necessarily have to be subclasses of `UIActivityItemProvider`. `UIActivityItemProvider` is just a class that conforms to this protocol.

Comment: you should not implement the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol in your view controller. `UIActivityItemProvider` implements the methods for this protocol.

Comment: Note for anyone else: make sure to use "initWithPlaceholderItem" when initializing your provider. Can just pass any string.

Answer (score 31):

You can implement the protocol wherever you want, even your viewcontroller is fine. Just instantiate the activityViewController with `initWithActivityItems:@[self]`.

Comment: Can you exactly tell why do we need to add "self" in "initWithActivityItems:"

Comment: If you set your ViewController to be your UIActivityItemSource then you need to tell the UIActivityViewController.

Comment: Ten years later, this is still the vital hint.

Answer (score 21):

The answer by [JotWee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725834/jotwee) helped me out.

There is no need for sub classing, `UIActivityItemSource` protocol methods can be implemented in view controller where share button is implemented.

Very important to add `self` in activity items array, like this (as JotWee suggested):

```
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self, url, image, nil];
```

Here is my final implementation:

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActivityItemSource>
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)shareBarButtonItemClick:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/images/1.jpg"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];

    NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self, url, image, nil];

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    return @"Summary Text";
}

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
{
    return @"";
}

- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController subjectForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    return @"Subject";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggybagging off of what **JotWee** and **Sihad Begovic** had provided, here's the **Swift 5.0** version of making your `ViewController` adopts the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol and using `share` barButtonItem to trigger the sharing of objects with other apps on your iPhone(s), and or, iPad(s):

Inside the **`viewDidLoad`** method of your `ViewController` class, implement the following:

```
 navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareBarButtonItemClicked(_:)))
```

And somewhere outside your **`viewDidLoad`** method, but inside your `ViewController` class, let us implement the `shareBarButtonItemClicked` method as below:

```
@objc func shareBarButtonItemClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //Here, iOS requires that you use self for your array of items 
    let items = [self]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)

    //App activities to be excluded from sharing to
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivityType.airDrop,
        UIActivityType.print,
        UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivityType.addToReadingList
    ]

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        if activityVC.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIViewController.popoverPresentationController)) {
            activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
        }
    }

    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now here's where things gets interesting. We need to make your `ViewController` class conform to the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol and implement its required methods as below:

```
extension ReferAFriendViewController: UIActivityItemSource {
func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
    return String(describing: "Sharing my awesome app")
}

func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
    return String(describing: "Sharing my awesome app")
}

// Now you can modify and use the same above method if you want different messages/info to be presented for different apps user selects to share with. 
// The Secret is utilizing the activityType parameter. 
// You just have to uncomment below method and swap it with above method.

/*
func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
    if activityType == .postToTwitter {
    return "Download #MyAwesomeApp via @vickSwift."
    } else if activityType == .mail {
        return String(describing: "My awesome app is lit. So download it")
    } else {
        return String(describing: "Download my awesome app")
    }
}
*/

// Now note that when you share your app via a mail app, you might need to provide `subject` line. 
// In fact, the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol provide us an optional delegate method to accomplish just that; implemented below: 
func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
    return String(describing: "My Awesome app email's subject title")
}
}
```

And that's how you adopt your class to conform to the UIActivityItemSource protocol and implement its methods. For more readings, I find this [web article from HackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example) website very really insightful.

Happy coding!