# Display all the possible share destinations / apps in a UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a requirement to share an:

1. Image
2. Text
3. URL

I have the following apps installed on my device:

1. Mail
2. Facebook
3. SnapChat
4. Instagram
5. Twitter
6. TikTok

When trying to share using the standard `UIActivityViewController` code

```
private func launchActivityController(withItems items: [Any])
{
    let activityViewController
        = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items,
                                   applicationActivities: nil)
    present(activityViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Here are my results when the `items` array consists of the following:

1. **Image only:** I can see all the 6 destinations + some others mentioned above
2. **Image + Text:** I can see only IG, FB, Twitter and Mail but no snap and tik tok
3. **Image + URL:** I can see Mail, FB, Twitter and Snap but no IG and TikTok
4. **Image + Text + URL:** I can see Mail, FB, Twitter but no IG, Snap and TikTok

I have 2 questions:

1 - Is anyone aware some kind of documentation for the popular platforms (IG, Snap, TikTok) on what type of content they support with the `UIActivityViewController` for example:

[image]

2 - And the more important question, Is it possible to prepare sharing data in different ways so that we can see every possible sharing destination in the `UIActivityViewController` and then retrieve only the supported data type once the share destination is chosen

**What I tried**

I have tried what [this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28187294/1619193) using `UIActivityItemSource` like so:

```
extension CouponViewController: UIActivityItemSource
{
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem
    (_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any
    {
        return UIImage()
    }

    func activityViewController
    (_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController,
     itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any?
    {
        return UIImage()
        
        // I can't send a different type or an array of items
    }
}
```

The issue is, I can only send one type, not an array of types. The type returned in `activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem` cannot be different from `itemForActivityType activityType` as well so it seems I can just return String, UIImage or URL.

When I return an array of different types (for example a UIImage, a String), nothing shows up in the share sheet, it is just blank.

Another interesting solution I tried [was mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380570/share-image-with-hashtag-via-uiactivityviewcontroller-twitter-facebook-instag) where I created a custom type for each share type, one for URL, one for UIImage and one for String and then I initialize the activity controller like this

```
UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [ImageProvider(),
                                         TextProvider(),
                                         URLProvider()],
                         applicationActivities: nil)
```

However, I am back to square one as it again only shows me destinations that support all three types of content

Just a repeat of the question incase you got to the end:

Is it possible to prepare sharing data in different ways so that we can see every possible sharing destination in the `UIActivityViewController` and then retrieve only the supported data type once the share destination is chosen

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: @MichaelFransen - unfortunately no. In the end I just dropped the URL I guess as I embedded the URL into the text.